# Multi-threaded application loses threads in the middle of processing

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to crawl some information from multiple websites.

The java application that I wrote collects information from one websites according to given command line argument in the beginning of the application.

I am running about 5 processes (meaning that I am crawling from 5 websites) simultaneously. In each process, i am running about 5 threads to collect information. The issue is that threads appear to be finished early via skipping without collecting some of the information.

Here is the part where fixed number of threads (5) are submitted (please read the comments for the explanation of the issue)

```
String className = collector.getClass().getName();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(collector.getMaxNoOfThreads());
for (ListPageLink listPageLink : listPageLinks) {

  Runnable runnable = () -> {
    List<MetaBook> metaBooks;
    Collector newCollector = null;
    try {
      newCollector = ((Collector) Class.forName(className)                                       
        .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
      metaBooks = newCollector.collectMetaBooksFromSingleLPL
                                    (listPageLink); //Here the collecto returns collected metaBooks successfully and I am logging the collected metabooks with a logger. 

      for (MetaBook metaBook : metaBooks) { //However here, the application runs for loop for a couple of metaBook and then suddenly thread quits. Because of this, i lose some of the information.
        newCollector.collectBook(metaBook);
      }
      newCollector.saveOrUpdateLPLInDB(listPageLink);

      ThreadHelper.sleep(newCollector.getRequestDelayMs());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      if (newCollector != null)
        newCollector.logError(e1);
    }
  };  //end of Runnable
  executor.execute(runnable);
}
collector.finishExecutorShutDown(executor);
```

Here is the related methods from Collector.java file:

```
public List<MetaBook> collectMetaBooksFromSingleLPL(ListPageLink listPageLink) {
    List<MetaBook> metaBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    MDC.put("classname", logClassName);

    try {
        logger.info("ListPageLink: " + listPageLink);
        metaBooks = crawler.extractMetaBooks(listPageLink
                .getLink());
        for (int i = 0; i < metaBooks.size(); i++)
            logger.info((i + 1) + ") " + metaBooks.get(i).getLink());

        logger.info("MetaBooks Size: " + metaBooks.size());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
    MDC.remove("classname");

    return metaBooks;
}



public Book collectBook(MetaBook metaBook) {
    if (sellerId == 0)
        sellerId = saveSellerInDbIfNotExists(seller);
    Book book = null;
    MDC.put("classname", logClassName);

    try {
        logger.info("MetaBook: " + metaBook);
        Book foundBook = hibernateBookDao.find(metaBook.getLink());
        if (foundBook != null) {
            book = new Book(metaBook);
            hibernateBookDao.updatePrice(book);
            foundBook = hibernateBookDao.find(metaBook.getLink());
            book = foundBook;
        } else {
            book = bookDataExtractor.extractBookData(metaBook);
            if (book.isAlive()) {
                book.setSellerId(sellerId);
                hibernateBookDao.saveOrUpdate(book);

                logger.info("Book Name: " + book.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }

    MDC.remove("classname");
    return book;
}

public void finishExecutorShutDown(ExecutorService executor) {

    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
}
```

Here is an example log file where you can see that metaBooks are collected but they are not fed into 'collectBook' method:

```
10:39:30:421 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-9 |  | ListPageLink: https://www..com/index.php?p=Products&ctg_id=2021&sort_type=rel-desc&page=2164
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 1) https://www..com/m-alice-legrows/bizenghast-kayip-ruhlar-kasabasi.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 2) https://www..com/amy-reeder-hadley/aptallarin-altini.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 3) https://www..com/david-hine/zehirli-seker.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 4) https://www..com/victor-hugo/sefiller-31.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 5) https://www..com/johann-wolfgang-von-goethe/genc-wertherin-acilari-2.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 6) https://www..com/charles-dickens/iki-sehrin-hikayesi-14.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 7) https://www..com/recaizade-mahmut-ekrem/araba-sevdasi-16.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 8) https://www..com/samipasazade-sezai/serguzest-15.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 9) https://www..com/namik-kemal/intibah-17.htm
10:39:32:885 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | 10) https://www..com/mehmet-rauf/eylul-20.htm
10:39:32:886 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | MetaBooks Size: 10
10:39:32:887 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | MetaBook: https://www..com/m-alice-legrows/bizenghast-kayip-ruhlar-kasabasi.htm
10:39:32:891 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | MetaBook: https://www..com/amy-reeder-hadley/aptallarin-altini.htm
10:39:32:895 | INFO  | pool-2-thread-12 |  | MetaBook: https://www..com/david-hine/zehirli-seker.htm
```

As you can see in the log, only 3 out of 10 metabook is processed by collectBook method.

This doesn't happen when I run the application alone (without other 4 processes). Everything works fine. I don't know if this is due to an OS or JVM limitation or there is something wrong with my code.

I would be happy if you could give a hand in this issue.

Thank you

Edit:

modified collectBook method against database lock:

```
public Book collectBook(MetaBook metaBook) {
    if (sellerId == 0)
        sellerId = saveSellerInDbIfNotExists(seller);
    Book book = null;
    MDC.put("classname", logClassName);

    try {
        logger.info("MetaBook: " + metaBook);
        Book foundBook;

        synchronized (CollectorsUtil.getCollectors()) {
            foundBook = hibernateBookDao.find(metaBook.getLink());
        }
        if (foundBook != null) {
            book = new Book(metaBook);

            synchronized (CollectorsUtil.getCollectors()) {
                hibernateBookDao.updatePrice(book);
                foundBook = hibernateBookDao.find(metaBook.getLink());
            }

            book = foundBook;
        } else {
            book = bookDataExtractor.extractBookData(metaBook);
            if (book.isAlive()) {

                synchronized (CollectorsUtil.getCollectors()) {
                    book.setSellerId(sellerId);
                    hibernateBookDao.saveOrUpdate(book);
                }

                logger.info("Book Name: " + book.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }

    MDC.remove("classname");
    return book;
}



private long saveSellerInDbIfNotExists(Seller seller) {
    Seller foundSeller;

    synchronized (CollectorsUtil.getCollectors()) {
        foundSeller = hibernateSellerDao.find(seller.getLink());
        if (foundSeller == null || foundSeller.equals(new Seller())) {
            hibernateSellerDao.save(seller);
        }
        foundSeller = hibernateSellerDao.find(seller.getLink());
    }
    this.seller = foundSeller;
    return foundSeller.getId();
}
```

Comment: Well I can tell you it's not a limitation of the operating system or the JVM. You get proper errors when hard limits are reached, and they're not going to be reached with 25 threads.

Comment: Based on a quick glance of the code there doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong. I'd guess that since it shows up when you're giving more work to the CPU it's a concurrency issue somewhere in your code. Or an issue with your logging, there are some odd constructs there.

Comment: what do you do in `collector.finishExecutorShutDown(executor);` ?

Comment: @diginoise, i added the corresponding finish method.

Comment: Have you verified that there's not a database deadlock happening in `collectBook`?

Comment: @EB what is the role (and declaration) of `MDC` ?

Comment: @Kayaman, I modified collectBook method against DB lock, is this approach correct?

Comment: @diginoise, MDC is to register the current class to the logger.

Comment: ... also could you add a logging statement to `collectBook() [...] if (foundBook != null) { //log something here } ` code path?

Comment: How about removing all synchronized (CollectorsUtil.getCollectors()) and see what happens? It is never a good idea to mix database locks with application locks, you can deadlock. If it helps introduce locking in the database for correctness instead.

Comment: @ewramner, originally, synchronized (CollectorsUtil.getCollectors()) code blocks are not there, i added them now and trying right now.

Comment: logging is a bit complex (unnecessarily?) too... you should have an instance of logger from some factory for your class... it means you would get the same instance. By registering and de-registering class names from logger, could you be missing some log entries? What is the interplay of these from different threads? Just create loggers and log explicitly to be sure you can see the whole picture.

Comment: No that approach will not work. The `collectBook` method looks like it should run in a transaction. Using `synchronized` won't work if you're starting multiple JVMs, and it should never be used like that anyway. You should check the database for deadlocks first before you try random fixes.

Comment: @Kayaman, if there would be a deadlock in DB, the application should not continue to crawl and write new data into DB,right?

Comment: Take a thread dump (`kill -3`) and have a look at how many threads you have and what they are busy with.

Comment: A deadlock doesn't mean the whole database is unusable. It can stop two of your threads from storing data though.

Comment: It's also possible you're getting an error condition such as running out of memory, and that's causing threads to die silently.  You can [add an UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to your code, and you might even have to add a `catch (Throwable t)...` to see it.